# How long should it take for an xcm message to reach its destination

Tags: xcm, xcmp

Given normal conditions, how long would should each of the XCM protocols [HMP, DMP, UMP] take for a message to reach its destination.

For example if i was a parachain and wanted to call a smart contract on phala.

Comment: For what purpose is this question being asked for? If it is used for some kind of synchronous operation, then this is an anti-pattern in XCM.

Comment: @KeithYeung For the sake of curiosity. I assume then you dont require a response from the receiving chain?